# How do I add background text or image to BIRT report?

Tags: java, image, text, background, birt

I have to add text or background image as "DRAFT" for report  when it match certain condition.I have to dynamically enable or display birt report back ground text ?

I am looking forward to  hear any ideas.

Thanks In Advance.
Thillakan.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To set up a static background image as you would:

- Select the master page in your report workspace.
- Select the "Properties" tab.
- Expand the Simple Master Page" section.
- Set the background image.

However, to make it dynamic based on something (such as a parameter), you can use Javascript to manipulate the report items directly. This is covered in chapter 13 of "[Integrating and Extending BIRT](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321580303)" which, along with "[BIRT, A Field Guide to Reporting](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321442598)", every BIRT report designer should have.

The easiest way is to name your master page specifically in the report designer and use `ReportDesignHandle.findElement(<name>)` to get its handle. Then use a setter to dynamically change the background image. The `beforeRender` script is the one where you want to put all this code which sets the background image.

Comment: Hi pax,
          Thanks for your info. In addition to this, I created a style and set the style to Simple Master Page" section.

   I put the static background image but when i  tried  to view as PDF report, back ground image does not appear. It works for html viewer.

  I had access to  A Field Guide to Reporting but it is some where lost :(.

     Anyway thanks for your time, I will look in to the scripting part.

Thillakan

Comment: The field guide is okay but you'll need the integrating/extending book if you want to do really fancy Java/Javascript report manipulation.